# jQuery sortable() - move elements to connected list before first element that is not sortable

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I have two connected sortable lists. The second contains only one element and it can't be moved ( but the list is sortable ).

When I move element from the first list to the second, I can't add the new element as first element of the second list.

Always first element of the second list is 5 (in this example). [http://jsfiddle.net/fuQ4Z/ Example](http://jsfiddle.net/fuQ4Z/) `.`

Ideas how to solve this problem ?

Thanks

Comment: $( ".connectedSortable" ).sortable({
      connectWith: ".connectedSortable",
    }).disableSelection();

http://jsfiddle.net/fuQ4Z/2/

Comment: In this case I'm able to move all items. I want to have one item in list which cant be moved.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you want the li of your #sortable2 to be sortable but not connected with the other list or draggable.
To accomplish this just add another class to the list element and exclude it.
http://jsfiddle.net/fuQ4Z/3/

```
$( "#sortable1, #sortable2" ).sortable({
  connectWith: ".connectedSortable",
  items: "li:not(.new)",
  cancel: '.excluded'
}).disableSelection();
```

I gave the li element on #sortable2 a excluded class instead of the new class..

```
<li class="ui-state-highlight excluded">Item 5</li>
```

Comment: Can I make Item5 always to be last element in both lists? Always to add elements before this Item ?